# Add review module to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

How do I **add the review block** that is visible on the category pages, to the home on the right side FROM THE BLOG is located.
Do I need to just insert the block type in the cms page? I hoped just adding something like this:

`{{block type="amreview/sidebar" template="amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml"}}`

www.fleshlight-expert.nl
http://www.fleshlight-expert.nl/men/shirts.html

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQMyre

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="amreview/sidebar" template="amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

use this xml code

Comment: thanks, but i have a 1 column homepage layout. Where do i put this code?

Comment: But i have 1 column homepage layout. where to place this then? and it is not possible to use {{block type="amreview/sidebar" template="amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml"}}

Comment: you put this in your frontend xml file. and if its 1-column than write content in refereance name tab

Comment: i update my code you just paste it in your frontend layout file

Comment: hey @bramvds did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue block with whitelist

go to `adminpanel->system->permission->block`

and click on add Button and add your block `amreview/sidebar` and enable it

and click on save and flush magento cache and check

Comment: Thanks did that, but what to do than? Can i use {{block type="amreview/sidebar" template="amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml"}} and put that in the cms homepage???

Comment: @bramvds Yes you can use this block in cms page and cms block after whitelist it

Comment: @bramvds If my answer solve your concern then here is an option where you can accept my answer so other users who has same problem take benifit from this

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. the amreview/sidebar is added and allowed. emptied cache. added {{block type="amreview/sidebar" template="amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml"}} like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoeEGP

Comment: @bramvds do some echo in `amreviewamreview/sidebar.phtml` file and check this  sidebar works or not ?

Comment: Hi Murtuza, thanks for the advice but i don't know what do some echo is? sorry, but i'm just a very basic magento user i think.

Comment: @bramvds open that file and write `<?php echo 124; ?>` and check whether this coming or not if not then your block is not called

Comment: and how can i check if this is coming?